# ODE Proof - Intersection of the family of solutions and the line $t = k$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that if the family of solutions of the differential equation
$$y′+p(t)y=q(t), p(t)q(t) \neq 0$$ is cut by the line $t=k$, the tangent lines to each member of the family at the points of intersection all intersect at one point.

This is for homework and I would really appreciate a hint. I get the general solution $$y = e^{- \int p(t) dt}(\int q(t) e^{\int p(t) dt} dt + C)$$ which is just the general solution for first order linear equation. But then I'm confused what the question is asking. Any **clarifications on the question** would be much appreciated.

The only thing I can think of right now is differentiating the solution but that's definitely not the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Wow!  Cool problem!***  Sorry if I got carried away and presented a complete solution, but once I had explained wassup here, I was just too close to the end to not conclude.  Anyway, hope this helps!

So here's what I think is going on: envision with the mind's eye, if you will, a cartesian coordinate system in $\Bbb R^2$, with the $t$-axis horizontal and the $y$-axis vertical; the graphs of functions $y(t): \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are the sets

$\{(t, y(t)) \mid t \in \Bbb R\} \subset \Bbb R^2, \tag 1$

and any line of the form

$t = k \tag 2$

passes through the point $(k, 0)$ and is parallel to the $y$-axis; as such, it is the set

$\{ (k, y) \mid y \in \Bbb R \}. \tag 3$

I assume that

$p(t), q(t) \in C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R); \tag 4$

that is, $p, q: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are everywhere continuous functions of $t$; then through any point $(k, y_1)$ of the line (3) there exists precisely one solution $y(t)$ to

$y'(t) + p(t)y(t) = q(t), \; y(k) = y_1, \tag 5$

as follows from the standard Picard-Lindeloef theorem; since the function $q(t) - p(t)y$ is both jointly continuous in $t$ and $y$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$ (an easily-verified result I leave to my myriad readers), it meets the hypothesis of the theorem and hence we establish existence and uniqueness for (5).

Now the slope of the line tangent to such a solution at $(k, y(k))$ is in fact

$y'(k) = q(k) - p(k)y(k) = q(k) - p(k) y_1; \tag 6$

therefore the equation of the *line* tangent to such a $y(t)$ at $(k, y(k)) = (k, y_1)$ is

$y - y_1 = (q(k) - p(k) y_1)(t - k); \tag 7$

likewise the tangent line at $(k, y_2)$ is

$y - y_2 = (q(k) - p(k) y_2)(t - k); \tag 8$

we see that for $y_2 \ne y_1$ these two lines have different slopes, hence are not parallel, hence they intersect at a unique point which may be found by equating their $y$-values for some as yet to be determined $t$:

$ (q(k) - p(k) y_1)(t - k) + y_1 = (q(k) - p(k) y_2)(t - k) + y_2; \tag 9$

thus,

$y_1 - y_2 = ((q(k) - p(k)y_2) - (q(k) - p(k) y_1))(t - k) = p(k)(y_1 - y_2)(t - k), \tag{10}$

or

$p(k)(t - k) = 1, \tag{11}$

or

$t = \dfrac{1}{p(k)} + k; \tag{12}$

observe that (12) is legitimized by the given hypothesis $p(t)q(t) \ne 0$, which implies $p(k) \ne 0$; furthermore, we may determine the corresponding $y$-value from (7) or (8):

$y = (q(k) - p(k) y_1)(t - k) + y_1 = \dfrac{(q(k) - p(k) y_1)}{p(k)} + y_1 = \dfrac{q(k)}{p(k)}; \tag{13}$

we thus see that the intersection point $(1/p(k) + k, q(k)/p(k))$ depends only on $k$,$p(k)$ and $q(k)$ and is thus completely independent of the value $y(k)$; therefore all such tangent lines pass through $(1/p(k) + k, q(k)/p(k))$, intersecting there, and we are done. $OE\Delta$

Comment: I know I'm suppose to reserve this for useful comments, but WOW just WOW. Thank you sensei.

Comment: You are most welcome my friend!